# Improve code readability when use list of variables

Tags: python

I'd like to create a list of communities in a more readable way, instead of doing it manually.

For example, the following returns 5 communities (but this number can change):

```
c = list(greedy_modularity_communities(G))
```

Then I define the 5 clusters as follows:

```
c_0 = sorted(c[0])
c_1 = sorted(c[1])
c_2 = sorted(c[2])
c_3 = sorted(c[3])
c_4 = sorted(c[4])
c_5 = sorted(c[5])
```

and print them

```
print(c_0)
print(c_1)
print(c_2)
print(c_3)
print(c_4)
print(c_5)
```

Do you know a way to iterate across variables (c_0, c_1, ...), from creation to printing, to improve code readability?

Comment: "I'd like to create" -- create what? Don't leave me hanging! :)

Comment: I accidentally deleted part of the text. Sorry for that and thanks for letting me notice it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions:

```py
c = list(greedy_modularity_communities(G))

clusters = [sorted(c[i]) for i in range(6)]
for cluster in clusters:
    print(cluster)
```

Or, if you want to get the cluster from all the communities instead of the first six:

```py
clusters = [sorted(community) for community in greedy_modularity_communities(G)]
for cluster in clusters:
    print(cluster)
```

Comment: You can use `itertools.islice` as well: `clusters = [sorted(c) for c in islice(greedy_modularity(communities(G)), 6)]`.